# How to stop bookmark from crashing PDF app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, pdf, pdfkit

I have a PDF Reader app using PDFKit with iOS 13 Swift, which has a bookmark button that can bookmark a particular page. It works fine for me while I am still looking at my PDF, but if I bookmark at least 1 page in my PDF and go back to my file browser, and pick my PDF again, the app crashes.
Here is my code:

```
private func updateBookmarkStatus() {
        if let documentURL = pdfDocument?.documentURL?.absoluteString,
            let bookmarks = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: documentURL) as? [Int],
            let currentPage = pdfView.currentPage,
            let index = pdfDocument?.index(for: currentPage) {
            bookmarkButton.image = bookmarks.contains(index) ? #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Bookmark-P") : #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Bookmark-N")
        }
    }
```

and it crashes with

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
```

This update function is called upon loading each separate page of the PDF. However, when I exit and enter my PDF again, it crashes here because I think Swift can't find the array of bookmarks since at least one has been marked. My app only crashes if I mark at least 1 bookmark, then exit to my file browser, then open my PDF again.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: try: let currentPage = pdfView?.currentPage,

Comment: @MohitKumar Where should I put that?

Comment: In your if statement...3rd let statement

Comment: is this working now?

Comment: @MohitKumar No, I can't put a try statement there. The entire sequence of "let" declarations are under an "if"...

Comment: I updated the code. It is supposed to show the bookmark (filled in or not, 2 images).

Comment: private func updateBookmarkStatus() {
        if let documentURL = pdfDocument?.documentURL?.absoluteString,
            let bookmarks = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: documentURL) as? [Int],
            let currentPage = pdfView?.currentPage,
            let index = pdfDocument?.index(for: currentPage) {
            bookmarkButton.image = bookmarks.contains(index) ? #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Bookmark-P") : #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Bookmark-N")
        }
    } Try this code